# How to debug server-side JScript code

Tags: .net, debugging, asp-classic, jscript

I need to maintain a classic ASP project which requires debugging server-side JScript code.
For example, consider an A.aspx file with the following code:

```
<% @Page Language="JScript" aspcompat="true" %>
<%
var a = 1;
var b = a + a;
...// Other statements here
Response.Write(b);
%>
```

In Visual Studio, I cannot put any breakpoint on any server-side jscript lines or blocks,
e.g. put a breakpoint on line `var b = a + a;`

However, it's okay for client-side javascript code debugging.
It becomes a big pain for me to debug code like this.

I want to know how to debug server-side jscript code or if any tools support such features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/06/24/432308.aspx) online but I haven't tried before.

So far I try to debug in writing it on the scree by

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="JavaScript" %>
<%
var blnTrace;
var strTrace = Application("g_Trace");
if (strTrace && strTrace.toUpperCase() == "TRUE")
    blnTrace = true;
else
    blnTrace = false;

var a = 1;
var b = a + a;
...// Other statements here

if (blnTrace)
{
    Response.Write(b);
}

...// Other statements here
```

%>

So that I can turn on/off the debug message.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue recently while working on an old website.

You can cause the application to break by calling [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debugger.break).

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug the website, when the application hits that line of code it will behave the same as if there is a breakpoint there.

Make sure to remove this before you move to a production enviroment or set `Debug="false"`

```
<% @Page Language="JScript" aspcompat="true" %>
<%
var a = 1;
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
var b = a + a;
...// Other statements here
Response.Write(b);
%>
```